# How to write huge data from Java to HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Our Java application generates huge data (long running program), but unable to store the data efficiently.

```
Public class HDFSWriter {
    FSDataOutputStream out = null;
    FileSystem fs = null;
    Configuration conf = null;
    static int linescounter = 0;

    void CreateHDFSFile() {
        Path filePath = new Path("filename.CSV");
        conf = new Configuration();
        fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        out = fs.create(filePath);
    }

    void writeHDFSFile(String csvLine) {
        out.writeBytes(csvLine);
        linescounter++;
        if(linescounter>=500) {
            linescounter=0;
            out.writeBytes(csvLine);
            //out.hsync();
            //out.hflush();
        }
    }

    void close() {
        fs.close();
    }
}
```

`CreateHDFSFile` method is called start of the program.

`writeHDFSFile` method is called for each line to insert into HDFS File.

`close` method is called at end of the program.

Even though I invoke `hsync` or `hflush`, data is not appearing in HDFS. It's appearing only after the complete program is completed i.e, after `fs.close()`.

How to make the data available during the HDFS file is created or at every time interval or particular number of records?

Comment: A few questions before I can answer: if your job is so big, why are you processing it with a Java application? How long does this job run for? Do you need access to this data at intermediate stages?

Comment: This is a kind of streaming job, It continuously produces data. We need to create one file per day in HDFS. Yes, This data should be available at intermediate stages.

Comment: Then you'd have to look at Storm and the HdfsBolt (http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_user-guide/content/ch_storm-using-hdfs-connector.html). Having a non-distributed Java job processing real-time big data is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: Storm HDFS Bolt have some limitations.... It generates multiple files based on RotationPolicy and filenames will have a naming format instead of standard file names and comma shouldn't be used as delimiter....